# Помогите разобрать как устроен parallax

Tags: parallax

помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться как на главной странице сайта https://www.bighorrorathens.com/ был выполнен parallax

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_lookat почти одно и тожн

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_instancing_performance